# trick to place 100 divs next to each other without wrap/newline/linebreak?

Tags: html, css

Are there some css statments which put a finite number of divs next to each other to the right without making a "linebreak/newline/wrap" and having a wrapper with a defined width?

Like putting 100 divs with 200px width and 60px height each next to each other on one line without a fixed width for a wrapper container?

Comment: Pretty sure you'd have to fix the width of a parent container and set the `overflow`.

Comment: hmm too bad! I want to avoid javascript to set the width of a wrapper dynamically...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The divs should have CSS:

```
display:inline-block;
```

And a containing div around them:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

Comment: @Jurudocs change `display: inline` to `display: inline-block`

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
.yourclass{
float:left;
width:200px;
height:60px;
}
```

working link http://jsfiddle.net/TmSdx/

Comment: This answer directly contradicts the OP's request to have a container div with *no defined width*.